# Web Service call to Service Cloude

Tags: apex, trigger, webservices, marketing-cloud-connect

I have a trigger that is ultimately going to send a mailing in Marketing Cloud when triggered from Service Cloud. This request will need to be two requests, one to get an auth token and a second using the auth token to send the message. I'm failing on part one of this request:

```
public static Integer getAPIToken(){
    Http http = new Http();
    HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
    request.setEndpoint('https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken');
    request.setMethod('POST');
    request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');


    jsonWrapper wrap = new jsonWrapper();
    wrap.clientId = 'xxxxx';
    wrap.clientSecret = 'yyyy';
    String jsonBody = json.serialize(wrap);

    request.setBody(jsonBody);

    System.debug(request.getBody());

    try {
        HttpResponse res = http.send(request);
        System.debug('STATUS:'+res.getStatus());
        System.debug('STATUS_CODE:'+res.getStatusCode());
        System.debug('BODY: '+res.getBody());
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
            System.debug('ERROR: '+ e);
    }

    // handle for any response other than Success

    return 1;
}
```

The problem when I execute this function anon, i get a return of message unauthorized. To clarify the xxx an yyy up above is actually replaced with a working token and secret, and an analog of this request call works fine in postman. Any ideas why its not working when executed from SF itself?

Comment: Challenging question to answer accurately without specifics to address. Are you trying to troubleshoot a pair of webservice callouts from apex in Salesforce to the Marketing Cloud REST APIs?

Comment: Yes mark, I've updated the above with the actual call I'm making. As I mentioned, this works fine in postman, though obviously postman generates the request a lot more natively than I must do in Apex. I assume I'm doing something wrong in the apex object initiation.

Answer (score 1):

> I've tried using Fiddler, but it seems the service call isnt originating from my machine, so I can't inspect it.

Correct. Apex Code runs on the server.

> Are there any tools in the Dev console to be able to see the full request going over the wire?

Yes, set the debug level for callouts to finest. It won't show you the literal over-the-wire payload, but it'll show all the parameters, etc that was sent. In general, whatever you set is what will be sent.

> @future doesnt allow for a return type, which I (think) I have to do in order to provide my send mailing function call the token it needs to work.

Correct. The code runs asynchronously after the current transaction, so it can't possibly return a value, because the transaction that called the future method will no longer be running.

> Do I have to bundle all these calls up in a single function to make this work?

Not necessarily; you could chain Queueable methods, for example, or use the platform cache to store the token, or use a custom setting to store the token... Lots of different things you could do. However, you will need to do something to guarantee that the methods will be called in order, and, in theory, future methods could be reordered in a way where the token call wouldn't happen until after the main call. Putting both calls into a single method doesn't have to be "sloppy", either:

```
@future public static void getTokenAndCallout() {
  String token = getTokenFromServer();
  makeOtherCallToServer(token);
}
```

Where each method does just one thing.

Comment: Good call on the example at the bottom. Thats likely how I'm going to construct it once I get past token. I've set the logging to finest on the callouts and while I'm getting a little data, its not what I'd expect if i were seeing the entire request:

18:28:22:025 CALLOUT_REQUEST [39]|System.HttpRequest[Endpoint=https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken, Method=POST]

It seems to be just showing me the endpoint itself, no headers, no body. Should I take this to mean that I'm not properly attaching the body and headers to the request?